# ios11 didUpdateLocations not called

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ios11

I'm developing ios app using CLLocationManager.

Until ios10, I called startUpdatingLocation, then didUpdateLocations is called, And I got a Location information.

Now, I update iOS11 beta9 and Xcode beta6.
I called startUpdatingLocation, but didUpdateLocations was not called.
So I cannot get any location.

Location is core information on my app.
Is there anyone who got same problem? or can resolve this problem?
sorry for my poor english. thank you.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Thank you for asking. But I resolved this problem. The answer is below comment of question

Comment: Either post an actual answer with the solution if you think it will help others or delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 11 added new privacy key in info.plist, you should add any one of these, hope the addition in info.plist work for you.

```
/*
*      Either the NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key or both the
*      NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
*      keys must be specified in your Info.plist; otherwise, this method will do
*      nothing, as your app will be assumed not to support Always authorization.
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! i resolved this problem. I used "requestAlwaysAuthorization" for getting permission, but the problem was here. I have to use "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" from iOS11. After I fixed , didUpdateLocations was called.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on simulator please make sure the simulator sets the location to custom location. By default it's select none.
You can find it on simulator-> features -> locations
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add in Info.plsit

```
privacy - location usage description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Application NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

[image]

```
   func CheckLocationAuthorization()  {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            self.ShowLocationError()
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // Do stuff
        }
    } else {
        self.ShowLocationError()
    }
}

//MARK:Show location error
func ShowLocationError()   {
    _ = UIAlertController.showAlertInViewController(viewController: self, withTitle: kAlertTitle, message: "Please allow location for getting the current weather report", cancelButtonTitle: "Setting", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: nil, tapBlock: { (a, b, c) in
        if let url = URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I needed to change how to get user permission.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue. I had accidentally declared the method as a class method instead of an instance method.

```
+ (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
```

rather than

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
```

Once I change the "+" to a "-", everything worked fine.